# Regex не видит символ перед скобками

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Регулярное выражение: `>(?=([^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')[^(\"|\')]*(\"|\'))*(?![^(\"|\')]*(\"|\')))`

Текст:

```
> комментарий

print: "((var))"
```

оно не находит `>` если дальше в тексте есть `()`

Как это исправить, если учесть что текст может быть любым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас какие-то странные классы символов. Внутри них не надо ставить `(\'|\")`, это синтаксис для выбора одной из нескольких альтернатив любой длины вне класса символов. Должно быть `[^\"\']`, если Вы имели в виду «не одинарные и не двойные кавычки».

После замены получается `>(?=([^\"\']*(\"|\')[^\"\']*(\"|\'))*(?![^\"\']*(\"|\')))` (https://regex101.com/r/TN6OVf/1/). Не знаю, этого ли Вы хотели.

**P.S.** `(\'|\")` вне класса символов, с другой стороны, можно заменить на `[\'\"]`, получив `>(?=([^\"\']*[\"\'][^\"\']*[\"\'])*(?![^\"\']*[\"\']))` (https://regex101.com/r/TN6OVf/2).